# How to find all (group-based) rows containing MIN/MAX values for a particular column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have temporary table (`@TempPackages`) which looks like this:

```
EntryId (PK)    PackageId    SubProductID    SubProductSequence
1               1111         17              3
2               1111         28              4
3               1111         33              1
4               1111         67              5
5               1111         122             2
6               2222         18              4
7               2222         29              5
8               2222         33              9
9               2222         103             7
10              2222         99              11
11              3333         256             5
12              3333         333             6
13              3333         789             3
14              3333         1023            2
15              3333         9845            1
```

I need a query which will give me the rows with the minimum/maximum `SubProductSequence` value for each unique `PackageId`.  For the table above, the query would return this:

```
EntryId (PK)    PackageId    SubProductID    SubProductSequence
3               1111         33              1
4               1111         67              5
6               2222         18              4
10              2222         99              11
12              3333         333             6
15              3333         9845            1
```

The `EntryId` column was something that I added while trying to solve this, as it gives me a unique column to join the same table on to (to ensure I still only end up with 15 rows in my joined table).

I tried this - just to get the `MIN()`:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    @TempPackages p1
INNER JOIN
    @TempPackages p2 ON p1.EntryId = p2.EntryId
    AND p1.SubProductSequence = (
        SELECT
            MIN(SubProductSequence)
        FROM
            @DeparturesToUpdate)
```

Obviously this is wrong, because the `INNER JOIN` is superfluous and the `SELECT MIN()` clause is wrong as it selects the rows with the minimum *overall* sequence numbers, not the minimum sequence numbers *per* package.

Any suggestions about the best way to do this?

Comment: @MitchWheat - I can't see any inconsistencies.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: my mistake: min and max are on separate lines in output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to use the **[`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx)** function:

```
SELECT
    EntryId 
  , PackageId 
  , SubProductID 
  , SubProductSequence
FROM
  ( SELECT
        EntryId 
      , PackageId 
      , SubProductID 
      , SubProductSequence
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PackageId
                           ORDER BY SubProductSequence ASC)
          AS rna
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PackageId
                           ORDER BY SubProductSequence DESC)
          AS rnd
    FROM
        @TempPackages
  ) AS tmp 
WHERE
      rna = 1
   OR rnd = 1 ;
```

---

`ROW_NUMBER()` is a ranking function that is used with **[`OVER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)** clause. What it basically does in this case, is it groups the rows with same `PackageId` (that is done with the `PARTITION BY PackageId`), then orders them by `SubProductSequence` (ascending or descending) and assigns a row_number, starting from 1 for each packageId.

So, the subquery would return this, if it was run alone:

```
EntryId (PK)    PackageId    SubProductID    SubProductSequence  rna  rnd
3               1111         33              1                    1    5
5               1111         122             2                    2    4
1               1111         17              3                    3    3
2               1111         28              4                    4    2
4               1111         67              5                    5    1

6               2222         18              4                    1    5
7               2222         29              5                    2    4
9               2222         103             7                    3    3
8               2222         33              9                    4    2
10              2222         99              11                   5    1

15              3333         9845            1                    1    5
14              3333         1023            2                    2    4
13              3333         789             3                    3    3
11              3333         256             5                    4    2    
12              3333         333             6                    5    1
```

The `WHERE` condition added in the external query is obvious afterwards.

Comment: Thanks - works great.  I want to understand *why* this works as well, so I'll try to break this down into its sub-components to figure it out.  If you could add any clarifying comments it would be great.  Otherwise, thanks for the great answer!

Comment: @LeopardSkinPillBoxHat - Change the outer `select` to `select *` and comment out the `where` clause.  It should become clear how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Improving on Bohemian's idea -

```
;WITH MinMax AS
(SELECT  PackageId ,
    MIN(SubProductSequence) [Min],
    MAX(SubProductSequence) [Max]
FROM    @TempPackages
GROUP BY PackageId )

SELECT EntryId, SubProductSequence, TP.PackageId, SubProductID FROM @TempPkges TP
INNER JOIN MinMax MM ON TP.PackageId = MM.PackageId 
AND (SubProductSequence = MM.[Min] OR SubProductSequence = MM.[Max])
```

And then, you can add your own ORDER BY

Answer (score 0):

```
 WITH  t1 AS
 (SELECT PackageId,MIN(SubProductSequence) minm,MAX(SubProductSequence) maxm  
 FROM    #@TempPackages
 GROUPBY  PackageId
 )
 SELECT  pk.EntryId, pk.PackageId,pk.SubProductID,  pk.SubProductSequence 
 FROM  #@TempPackages pk INNER JOIN t1 
 ON pk.PackageId = t1.PackageId
 WHERE pk.SubProductSequence = t1.minm  OR
       pk.SubProductSequence = t1.maxm
```