# How to group rows based on Min value of the column in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, group-by, min

I am looking for a way to group rows based on the minimum value of a column. Below is the scenario.. Any help would be appreciated.

For eg:

[image]

My Query:

Select Id, Name, SUM(Price) As Price, GroupId, GroupName, Key
From #tmpTable
Group BY Id, Name, Price, GroupId, GroupName, Key

I'm trying to use the Row_Number() as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14062375/how-to-find-all-group-based-rows-containing-min-max-values-for-a-particular-co) post but having issues to get the SUM(price) of all similar GroupIds and Ids

My output is: 1 Test 300 3 G3

Vs

Expected output: 1 Test 600 3 G3

Thanks in advance!

---

Below is the query to resolve the issue I had. I'm still using Row_Number() and then rolling up Price to get the SUM. (nesting queries)

**ANSWER** Final Qry:

```
   Select Id, 
   Name, 
   SUM(Price) As Price, 
   GroupId, 
   GroupName
(
       Select Id, 
              Name, 
              SUM(Price) As Price, 
              GroupId, 
              GroupName, 
              Key, 
              Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY Id, GroupId ORDER BY Key) As rna
        From #tmpTable
        Group BY Id, Name, Price, GroupId, GroupName, Key
 ) As A
 Where rna = 1
 Group BY Id, Name, Price, GroupId, GroupName
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select Id, 
   Name, 
   SUM(Price) As Price, 
   GroupId, 
   GroupName
(
       Select Id, 
              Name, 
              SUM(Price) As Price, 
              GroupId, 
              GroupName, 
              Key, 
              Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY Id, GroupId ORDER BY Key) As rna
        From #tmpTable
        Group BY Id, Name, Price, GroupId, GroupName, Key
 ) As A
 Where rna = 1
 Group BY Id, Name, Price, GroupId, GroupName
```